# Could you explain the so called Java standard way to compute hashcode?

Tags: java, math, hashcode

I recently have to override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in Java. I hence looked for a fast and efficient way to compute hash codes.

Java developers seem to aggree on the following method :

```
    int hash = 23;
    hash = hash * 37 + paramOne;
    hash = hash * 37 + paramTwo;
    // And so on...
```

It might be simple arithmetic but I don't really get it. What are the garantees ? What are the corner cases ? Is there a better (rather simple) way to do it ?

Thank you !

Comment: Where does "Java developers seem to agree on the following method" come from?

Comment: hash functions are magical. You can analyse them and see if they work well, but its tough to explain why any particular numbers work.

Comment: @nhahtdh For instance : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/hash-code-implementation, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier (and accordingly to one answer bellow), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121524/understanding-of-hash-code, and so on, without counting my coworker's opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In words of Joshua Bloch (explaining the default implementation of `hashCode()` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29) in `String` class , that is :  `s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]`):

> The value 31 was chosen because it is an odd prime. If it were even and the multiplication overflowed, information would be lost, as multiplication by 2 is equivalent to shifting. The advantage of using a prime is less clear, but it is traditional. A nice property of 31 is that the multiplication can be replaced by a shift and a subtraction for better performance: 31 * i == (i << 5) - i. Modern VMs do this sort of optimization automatically.

For further reading , refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299304/why-does-javas-hashcode-in-string-use-31-as-a-multiplier) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835976/what-is-a-sensible-prime-for-hashcode-calculation).

Answer (score 2):

It's about prime factors. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3613382/25141).

If you're just looking for a fast way and pragmatic way to do it and you have no major concerns about performance, have a look at the Apache Commons Lang [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) or a similar library function.
There is an [equivalent builder](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) for `equals`.

Comment: I actually tried several version of hash code generation. Using the standard hard coded `31 * i` or `<< N - 1`, using `Objects.hash` and `HashCodeBuilder` and I found that `HashCodeBuilder` is about the same speed as the standard hard-coded one mentioned by Bloch (and internally it does the same calculations). I was surprised, but I assume this has to do with the JVM optimizing the code by inlining it all after some amount of initial calls. `Objects.hash` was one of the slowest, probably due to the behind-the-scenes array generation inherent in the `Object... objects` ellipsis parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Joshua Bloch tells you how to override equals and hashCode properly in chapter 3 of his "Effective Java".  Google for it and read it.

He's the guy who wrote the collections API and is *now* the chief Java architect for Google.  That's authoritative enough for me.

Comment: He's *not*? Should be *now*, I reckon.

Comment: Oh, my.  Thank you for pointing out my mistake.  Too early in the morning, typing in the dark.